# How to add and edit a short answer in multiple google forms

Tags: forms

So I have multiple google forms (around 20 forms), that I need to do 2 things to them:

1- These 20 forms are placed in a folder in my google drive. I need to add more like an "Access code" where users will have to insert in order to continue the solving the quiz.
The way I did that was to add a "short answer" question to "section 1" of the quiz asking "Enter your Access Code", add "response validation", "Regular expression" and "Pattern". Also making this a "required question". This should look something like the below picture
[Example of google form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNstH.png)

So is it possible to have a scriptto add this question to all 20 forms

2- The "access code" in these google forms will have to be updated frequently, so I don' want to be updating the "Pattern" manually for each form, is t possible to have a google script to edit the value of the pattern for each form

Thanks in advance guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue that I was having, through looking for different codes and here are the codes that I used.

N.B. The codes might not be very clean as I was copying them from other parts/projects, but they have worked for me

1- Update the 20 forms with adding the access code question, I figured it was not possible to add a question at a certain position in the google form, however I can add a question at the end of the form and then move this item to the position I want:

```
    function AddAccesscodeQ() {
  var filess = DriveApp.getFolderById("Drive id>").getFiles();
  while (filess.hasNext()) {
var file = filess.next();
var form = FormApp.openById(file.getId());

var sectionIndex= 0; // Please set the index you want to insert.

//I added a "sample item" to be moved and edited later
var newItemQ = form.addTextItem().setTitle("New sample item").getIndex(); // New sample item
// I added a Pagebreak that also should be moved after the questions "Enter Your Access Code"
var newItemPB = form.addPageBreakItem().getIndex(); 

var items = form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.PAGE_BREAK);
var sections = [0];
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
// I pushed the items in the google form twice downwards, to be able to move the "sample item" and "Page break" to the top of the form
  sections.push(items[i].getIndex());
  sections.push(items[i].getIndex());

}
var insertIndex = sections[sectionIndex + 1] || null;
if (insertIndex) {
// Here I moved the 2 new items to the desired positions
  form.moveItem(newItemQ, 0);
  form.moveItem(newItemPB, 1);
}
// Here I am going to edit the "Sample Question" to be as desired
  var itemss = form.getItems();
  var itemID = itemss[0].getId();
  var itemse = form.getItemById(itemID).asTextItem()
  .setTitle('Enter Your Access Code').setRequired(true);
  //Create validation rule
  var validation = FormApp.createTextValidation()
  .setHelpText('Invalid Code')
  .requireTextMatchesPattern("<Access Code>")
  .build();
  itemse.setValidation(validation);
  }
}
```

2- The second problem was that I later might need to change this access code to a new one for the 20 forms

```
function UpdateAccessCode() {
var filesPhCH = DriveApp.getFolderById("<Drive ID>").getFiles();
while (filesPhCH.hasNext()) {
var file = filesPhCH.next();
var form = FormApp.openById(file.getId());
var items = form.getItems();

  //Loop through the items and list them
  for (var i = 0;i<items.length;i++){
    var item = items[i];
    var itemID = item.getId();
    var itemtitle = item.getTitle();
    var itemindex = item.getIndex();
    // I found no need to continue the for loop since the items that need modification are at the top of the form
    if (itemindex == 0){
      break;
    }
  }
    //Select the question you want to update
  var itemse = form.getItemById(itemID).asTextItem()
  .setTitle('Enter Your Access Code');
  //Create validation rule
  var validation = FormApp.createTextValidation()
  //.setTitle('Enter Your Access Code');
  .setHelpText('Invalid Code')
  .requireTextMatchesPattern("<Enter the new Access Code>")
  .build();

  itemse.setValidation(validation);
}
}
```

I hope this might help someone as it has saved a lot of time for me ;)